# generate auxilary data file from the loop with stats-command

Tags: gnuplot

Here is an example of my data file:

```
Opt1    0   A   -1.3    3.9
Opt1    0   B   -1.3    3.9
Opt3    0   B   -1.4    3.9
Opt1    3   A   -2.4    14.7
Opt2    3   A   -2.3    13.2
Opt3    3   A   -2.5    17.2
Opt1    6   A   -2.9    21
Opt3    6   A   -2.9    25
Opt3    6   B   -2.9    25.3
Opt1    15  B   -4.2    22.4
Opt3    15  A   -4.1    24.8
Opt3    15  B   -4.2    25.5
Opt1    24  B   -5.9    23.8
Opt2    24  B   -5.3    20.1
Opt3    24  A   -5.6    22.8
Opt3    24  B   -5.7    23.2
```

which is basically X,Y-data with some extra columns for sorting purposes.

Here is my plot command:

`plot for [t in "0 3 6 15 24"] 'data.tsv' using 5:((stringcolumn(2) eq t) ? $4 : 1/0) w p`

which produces sets of points grouped by variable "t". Additionally I'd like to connect center of mass of each group with a line. For this I have a loop with stats command (from which I can get mean values for x and y): `do for [t in "0 3 6 15 24"]{
stats 'data.tsv' using 5:((stringcolumn(2) eq t) ? $4 : 1/0)
...}`

What I cannot figure out is how to capture variables STATS_mean_x and STATS_mean_y and append them for each t-value into $datablock or separate file which can later be plotted. (gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 4)

Sorry if it is just another silly question :) I've spent long time searching for a solution, but found nothing which would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect your STATS_mean values in a string and write them to a temporary file. Then you can plot the contents of this temporary file:

```
t_string = "0 3 6 15 24"

temp_data = ""
do for [t in t_string]{
  stats 'data.tsv' using 5:((stringcolumn(2) eq t) ? $4 : NaN)
  temp_data = temp_data.sprintf("%f %f\n", STATS_mean_x, STATS_mean_y)
}

set print "temp.dat"
print temp_data
unset print

set terminal png
set output "graph.png"
plot for [t in t_string] 'data.tsv' using 5:((stringcolumn(2) eq t) ? $4 : NaN) title t w lp, \
     'temp.dat' title "average" w lp
set output
```

PS: I have replaced your `plot w p` by `plot with lp` so that I can better see what's going on.

[image]